# Drawing on the background of a Winform Chart without overpainting the grid

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, data-visualization

I want to draw an Image to the background of a `DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`. Since the `ChartArea.BackImage` property only accepts a path to an image, you cannot set this value to a runtime image.

For this reason I took the `PrePaint Event` of the chart to draw on the chart graphic (I removed parts of the code and replaced the image with a blue rectangle):

```
private void chart1_PrePaint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    double xMax = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.X, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum);
    double xMin = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.X, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum);
    double yMax = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.Y, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum);
    double yMin = e.ChartGraphics.GetPositionFromAxis("ChartArea1", AxisName.Y, chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum);

    double width = xMax-xMin;
    double heigth = yMax- yMin;

    RectangleF myRect = new RectangleF((float)xMin,(float)yMin,(float)width,(float)heigth);
    myRect = e.ChartGraphics.GetAbsoluteRectangle(myRect);

    e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue), myRect);
}
```

The problem is, that this way the grid of the chart gets overwritten(see left chart). But I want the grid to be visible (see left chart). Any Ideas?

[image]

Comment: You could save out your in-memory image to a file in a temp directory and use the `ChartArea.BackImage` property you mention...

Comment: I'll try out, but I am a bit worried about the performance, since I want to update the background very often

Comment: Yes, that would be a concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Since the ChartArea.BackImage property only accepts a path to an image, you cannot set this value to a runtime image.*

Actually you **can** by making use of the obscure `NamedImage` class:

```
// here you can use any image..
Bitmap bmp = ... insert your image creation code!

// create a named image from it
NamedImage ni = new NamedImage("test", bmp);

// add it to the chart's collection of images
chart1.Images.Add(ni);

// now we can use it at any place we seemingly can only use a path:
chart1.BackImage = ni.Name;
```

The same trick also works for `DataPoint.BackImage` !

Performance is another question though but it should beat writing to disk any time..

Comment: Remember that for this case (Char area only) he should use: chart1.ChartAreas[0].BackImage = ni.Name;